# SSRS report repeat table for every parameter value

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

Guys sorry for the general question here but I have been looking on the internet and cant find a solution.

I have an SSRS report. There is one Parameter user must put in before running, @Location.

In the query its specified to only return results where that location is matched.
I.E. `where Company.location = @location`

The results are displayed in a table. This all works fine, but I want to change the parameter to contain multiple values.....and then repeat the table for every location the user chooses.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Step 1: Create a dataset for your multi-valued parameter, something like this:

```
SELECT LocationId, LocationName FROM MyLocations
```

Step 2: Create the parameter `@LocationId`, with available values from the above dataset, and set it to allow multiple values.

Step 3: Create another dataset along these lines for the actual table:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyDataTable tbl
WHERE tbl.Location IN (@LocationId)
```

Step 4: Create a List, bind it to the *second* dataset (select the list, find the "DataSet" property).

Step 5: Open the properties for the Details of the list, group on `LocationId`.

Step 6: Drop a tablix inside the list, and pick your fields from Dataset2 for that tablix at your leisure.

Step 7: ...

Step 8: Profit!

---

PS. There are several alternatives available to do this, including:

- Use a list for the location in combination with a subreport for the actual table.
- Use *one* big table, with groupings for location.

Comment: I'm imagining if I try the one big tablix option then with the correct formatting it should be possible to make it look like lots of little tables?

Comment: @whytheq yes, I've done so in the past. Blank rows between groups can help to do this.

Comment: @Jeroen on another issue what do you use to combat parameter sniffing in SSRS reports? Does `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` help?

Comment: @whytheq Not sure if comments on this question are the place to discuss new questions. You should try either a chat room (if your question is open ended), or post a new question if you have a concrete issue/problem. Good luck!