# How to repeat multiple tables in report For multiple values?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have one report in which I have table like below,

[image: This is what report looks like]

Now as for change I need to add the second table for each customer and the new report should look like as below,

[image: Expected report look]

So basically, I want to repeat two tables for each customer there will be multiple customers or single customer. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679620/ssrs-report-repeat-table-for-every-parameter-value) answer but with no luck. (The table should always visible so can not go with the drill down report.)
Any help would be great. My reporting server is 2008 r2.In case of the problem or confusion feel free to comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Jacob's answer, but make a subreport that handles all the tables and datasets for one single customer.

Then use a list object that is populated by a dataset of all the customers you want to display, and put the subreport in the list object, passing the customerId to the subreport.

Answer (score 2):

You need to place it(the table) in a list object. And configure the grouping of the list and filtering of your table.

Comment: but list can operate and bind to the one dataset at the time. But i have multiple tables which will be need to bind to the multiple datasets. Thanks though, for taking your time.

Comment: So if you have a fixed ammound of datasets, why using dynamic number of tables ?